# I am trying to populate an array with integers using for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am very new to object oriented programming and having some trouble getting my InitializeBoard method to work properly in my sliding puzzle project.  I keep getting an error that reads "expression must have pointer-to-object type" and another error that says "subscript requires array or pointer type".  Here is the code that I am currently working on...

```
// EXTERNAL DEPENDENCIES
#include "SlidingPuzzle.h"

// CONSTRUCTOR METHOD(S)
SlidingPuzzle::SlidingPuzzle() {
    this->rows = 3;
    this->cols = 3;
    InitializeBoard();
}

SlidingPuzzle::SlidingPuzzle(int newRows, int newCols) {
    // Attempt to set the requested number of rows
    if (this->setRows(newRows) == false) {
        this->rows = 3;
    }

    // Attempt to set the requested number of cols
    if (this->setCols(newCols) == false) {
        this->cols = 3;
    }

    InitializeBoard();
}

// SETTERS
bool SlidingPuzzle::setRows(int newRows) {
    // Only accept the new number of rows if number is non-negative
    bool newValueAccepted = false;
    if (newRows > 0) {
        this->rows = newRows;
        newValueAccepted = true;
    }

    return newValueAccepted;
}

bool SlidingPuzzle::setCols(int newCols) {
    // Only accept the new number of cols if number is non-negative
    bool newValueAccepted = false;
    if (newCols > 0) {
        this->cols = newCols;
        newValueAccepted = true;
    }

    return newValueAccepted;
}

// UTILITY METHOD(S)
void SlidingPuzzle::InitializeBoard() {
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this->theBoard[i][j] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like everything is fine up until the end of the code when I try to write the method for initializing the board.  Is anyone able to diagnose my problems?  I think what I am confused about is how to use a pointer with an array

----EDIT-----

```
my header file...
// PRE-PROCESSOR
#ifndef __SLIDINGPUZZLE__
#define __SLIDINGPUZZLE__

#define COLOR_DEFAULT   7
#define COLOR_RED       12
#define COLOR_GREEN     10

#define SLIDE_UP        1
#define SLIDE_DOWN      2
#define SLIDE_LEFT      3
#define SLIDE_RIGHT     4

// EXTERNAL DEPENDENCIES
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

// SLIDING PUZZLE OBJECT SPECIFICATION
class SlidingPuzzle {
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int** theBoard;

public:
    // CONSTRUCTOR METHOD(S)
    SlidingPuzzle();
    SlidingPuzzle(int newRows, int newCols);

    // GETTER METHOD(S)
    int getRows();
    int getCols();

    // SETTER METHOD(S)
    bool setRows(int newRows);
    bool setCols(int newCols);

    // UTILITY METHOD(S)
    void InitializeBoard();
    void PrintBoard();
    bool SlideTile(int directionCode);
    void ScrambleBoard();

};

#endif
```

Comment: How is `theBoard` declared or initialized? You can't just arbitrarily fill it up. Also in C++ strongly consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: How are you calling this class, please? And please give the `exact` error message, as it appears from your compiler, as text, and annotate what line in your code it's pointing to (don't just give a line number, we can't see your line numbers).

Comment: theBoard is initialized in my .h file... I will edit above with that code...

Comment: You never initialize your `theBoard` object. You need to allocate memory for it. Or better yet, use `std::vector`. And I know you didn't ask, but while `using namespace std;` is frowned upon, doing so in a header file is worse, because it poisons any file that includes it in the future.

Comment: If you MUST keep you `int** theBoard`, then you need to allocate memory for it `theBoard = new int*[newRows];` and then for each row in `theBoard` you need to allocate more memory `theBoard[i] = new int[newCols];` And then you have to remember to `delete[]` these `newRows + 1` memory allocations. That is, use `std::vector`